# java install issue

Tags: java, path, javac

I'm trying to write my first Java program named `HelloWorld` but I got stuck with the error below:

> javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java
>
> Usage: javac

My system: `Windows 10, 64bit`

path to file: `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk9.0.4\bin;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

I'm afraid that something is wrong with Java. When I type `java` in cmd I get error below:

> C:\Users\Kamil>java Usage: java [options]  [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [options] -jar  [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)    or  java [options] -m [/] [args...]
>          java [options] --module [/] [args...]
>              (to execute the main class in a module)
>
> Arguments following the main class, -jar , -m or --module 
>   / are passed as the arguments to main class.

where options include:

```
-d32          Deprecated, will be removed in a future release
-d64          Deprecated, will be removed in a future release
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
--class-path <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-p <module path>     A ; separated list of directories, each directory
              is a directory of modules.
--upgrade-module-path <module path>...
              A ; separated list of directories, each directory
              is a directory of modules that replace upgradeable
              modules in the runtime image
--add-modules <module name>[,<module name>...]
              root modules to resolve in addition to the initial module.
              <module name> can also be ALL-DEFAULT, ALL-SYSTEM,
              ALL-MODULE-PATH.
--list-modules
              list observable modules and exit
-d <module name>
--describe-module <module name>
              describe a module and exit
--dry-run     create VM and load main class but do not execute main method.
              The --dry-run option may be useful for validating the
              command-line options such as the module system configuration.
--validate-modules  validate all modules and exit
              The --validate-modules option may be useful for finding
              conflicts and other errors with modules on the module path.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|module|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version to the error stream and exit
--version     print product version to the output stream and exit
-showversion  print product version to the error stream and continue
--show-version
              print product version to the output stream and continue
--show-module-resolution
              show module resolution output during startup
-? -h -help
              print this help message to the error stream
--help        print this help message to the output stream
-X            print help on extra options to the error stream
```

Could someone help to recognize what it mean? I reinstalled it but it is still the same.

Comment: could someone check if the path is correct?

Comment: Include your project structure (i.e. where HelloWorld.java file is) and where do you run javac from?

Comment: C:\Users\Kamil>cd D:\practice

C:\Users\Kamil>javac HelloWorld.java
javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin

Comment: file HelloWorld.java is in folder "practice", in D

Comment: The file not found error you pointed above shows that the `cmd` didn't change directory. First do `cd D:` then do `cd practice` and see if the current path changes to `D:\practice` then run `javac HelloWorld.java`

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting comments, so that everything is in one place. Make it easy for others to help you. Not all comments will be shown by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Environmental Variables. Open command prompt and type javac. You will get a message ‘javac’ is not recognized. 4

Still you can’t start programing. You have to set the Environmental Variables. Open command prompt and type javac. You will get a message ‘javac’ is not recognized
. 
It  means command prompt application doesn’t know about java commands although you havesuccessfully installed the JDK. So how do we make it recognized or introduce java commands to the computer (command prompt)? Simply make the link between command prompt and the place where the java commands reside.

```
Right click My Computer > 
Properties > 
Advanced System Setting > Environment Variables.
```

Now you can add the path of the Java commands for the Path variable
Usually java installation directory resides in the following path:

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk.<version>/bin/
```

Comment: when I type javac I get message : C:\Users\Kamil>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  @<filename>                  Read options and filenames from file
  -Akey[=value]                Options to pass to annotation processors
  --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Root modules to resolve in addition to the initial modules, or all modules

Comment: on the module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATH.
  --boot-class-path <path>, -bootclasspath <path>
        Override location of bootstrap class files
  --class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
        Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -d <directory>               Specify where to place generated class files
  -deprecation
        Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -encoding <encoding>         Specify character encoding used by source files
  -endorseddirs <dirs>         Override location of endorsed standards

Comment: I changed path to:
 "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin";%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\                          and doesnt work still, again the same error javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>              Im really glad that someone it trying to help me

Comment: Type javac in the cmd and just comment the output.

Comment: as I write above, when I type javac I get: C:\Users\Kamil>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  @<filename>                  Read options and filenames from file
  -Akey[=value]                Options to pass to annotation processors
  --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*

Comment: Root modules to resolve in addition to the initial modules, or all modules
        on the module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATH.
  --boot-class-path <path>, -bootclasspath <path>
        Override location of bootstrap class files
  --class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
        Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors

Comment: --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Root modules to resolve in addition to the initial modules, or all modules
        on the module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATH.
  --boot-class-path <path>, -bootclasspath <path>
        Override location of bootstrap class files
  --class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
        Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -d <directory>               Specify where to place generated class files

Comment: and much more, its too long to type it here

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html      Download the latest jdk from the above link and reinstall the jdk properly. Then try again

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd.
After every line press enter:

```
D:
cd practice
javac HelloWorld.java
```